# Can I get eclipse (using maven, m2e) to throw an error/warning when main code references test code?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, maven, m2e

I am using Eclipse (4.2 Juno) with m2e with the default settings. Source code is in `src/main/java` and test code is in `src/test/java`.

Sometimes I inadvertently `import` some stuff from test to a class in main. Eclipse does not complain about this (both `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` are just configured as source folders when using m2e), and tests all run properly because the test environment (JUnit) can access code from both main and test. However, when I try to run main code by itself later (after it has been ostensibly tested), I will inevitably get a bunch of `ClassNotFoundException`s when trying to use the code.

Is there a way to get Eclipse to show errors or warnings when this happens?

Comment: If you run "mvn compile" your files will be compiled with the right Classpath.

Comment: You could have a maven-enforcer-plugin rule that is checking that nothing depends on test-jars, if that is what you mean. And you should let a CI system do what @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen suggests.

Comment: My project is too small right now to set up CI; I am pretty much the only committer right now. I'm also ashamed to say that I never bothered to figure out how to use maven from the commandline...I can't even get `mvn compile` to run without a bunch of other errors. For now I'd just like to know if I can just happy go on coding in Eclipse :)

Answer (score 0):

If your code in `src/main/java` refers to code in the `src/test/java`, it will simply not compile with Maven. No need to write your own enforcer rule for that.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no way to do this (that I know of). m2e gets the classpath wrong in other ways sometimes too, so you should get used to running the Maven build before you check in - irrespective of what Eclipse says about the code compiling.

See this presentation http://www.eclipsecon.org/europe2012/sites/eclipsecon.org.europe2012/files/EclipseConEU2012-m2e-talk.pdf (under 'Dependency Scopes') for more background.